# How to disable print statements conveniently so that pythonw can run?

Tags: python, pythonw

I have a python script (.py) which runs normally on the console. When I try running the script using pythonw by changing the extension to (.pyw), it stopped working. My guess is that the print statements are causing pythonw to die based on results returned from Google Search.

Is there a convenient way to disable the print statements so that pythonw can run? I have too many print statements in the script. Changing them one by one is not practical, particularly if I want to switch back to using normal python.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no clue what pythonw, but it sounds like you want to print to null, effectively making this question a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735917/redirecting-stdout-to-nothing-in-python

Comment: `"My guess is that the print statements are causing pythonw to die"` - Nope, doesn't seem to be the case in my quick test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your own print function, say `out`, and then change all `print`s to `out`.  the `out` method can then be changed once to output to console or to a file.

Comment: how would you use this solution if you're using library functions that call print?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered an answer from another StackOverflow thread which worked well for me. I have upvoted the answer. The credit is not mine. If you want to upvote, go to that link and upvote. See link below.

[Can I get the output of "print" statement in pythonw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674667/can-i-get-the-output-of-print-statement-in-pythonw#)

You can globally redirect stdout by assigning to sys.stdout:

`import sys
sys.stdout = open("mylog.txt", "w")`
Then the rest of your program's stdout, including print statements, will go to mylog.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect all output to /dev/null.  Python has a platform agnostic way to do this.

```
import os
import sys

# Only redirect for pythonw not regular python.
if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.executable))[0] == 'pythonw':
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

Comment: one question. Doing this , does it increase the speed at which scripts run? (since no print anymore)