# pygame program exits with no error message when run with pythonw

Tags: python-2.7, console, pygame, exit, pythonw

I'm trying to run a pygame program using pythonw to avoid having the console window show up. This causes a weird issue related to print statements.

Basically, the program will just exit after a few seconds with no error message. The more printing I do, the faster it happens.
If I run it in idle or at the command prompt (or in linux) the program works fine. This problem only happens when launched with pythonw (right-click, Open With, pythonw).

I'm using python 2.7.11 on Windows XP 32-bit. pygame 1.9.1release.

Is there a workaround for this? Why does the program simply terminate with no error?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

succeeded, failed = pygame.init()
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

terminate = False
while terminate is False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate = True    
    area = display_surface.fill((0,100,0))
    pygame.display.flip()                 
    elapsed = clock.tick(20)              
    print str(elapsed)*20
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: have you try to remove all `print` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674667/can-i-get-the-output-of-print-statement-in-pythonw

Comment: @furas Yes if the print statements are removed the problem disappears. However it took me a very long time to track down the issue to the print statements. If you are printing very little it can happen randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove print statements. Save them for later debugging. ;-)

Two steps to solve this problem:

- Firstly, keep all the code in `py` file - don't change it to `pyw` now; Say it is `actualCode.py`
- Then, create a new file `runAs.pyw` with the following lines in it

```
# In runAs.pyw file, we will first send stdout to StringIO so that it is not printed

import sys  # access to stdout
import StringIO  # StringIO implements a file like class without the need of disc

sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()  # sends stdout to StringIO (not printed anymore)

import actualCode  # or whatever the name of your file is, see further details below
```

Note that, just importing **actualCode** runs the file, so, in `actualCode.py` you **should not** enclose the code which is executed, in what I call `is it main running file` condition. For example,

```
# In actualCode.py file
....
....
....
if __name__ == '__main__':  # Don't use this condition; it evaluates to false when imported
    ...  # These lines won't be executed when this file is imported,
    ...  # So, keep these lines outside
# Note: The file in your question, as it is, is fine
```